# Unintelligible result opening csv in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, file-conversion

When I open a .csv file in excel this is what is showing up:

Maxtor Encryption ver 2.0.1.1.0 ³§o rkD`V’)cÿA®T7B‡LôŠì£\% i¼r1 ØÕë—„×½é¿wjd ´Íâ¿…Öö?HÐ)vM!W«Va<žÒ LåRpµI©ô Ès?¿%žfÇu9ä½''üÿ¸

egí¸8B¡–ì¶S@çä†Óüò˜¦.¦6„öð†’ãÍ%x#ÓcCôÿùT@°…À“f`´xŠM)œÌ¹¶~Í>;xÄhÀ’¨6É•—G„—É;{™t»_QyÅC²ä9pÏFb)£P8Õn®qnÑ™×¥ãG¨ò@1
"‘WHç†›–çýFÀÆ-?¬b)É\ÀÓÍ× á¥l²±Pdô”(J| „ öO%Xèe–Î8ycXÕÊ‰UI§˜v    IËòbótèd‰‡R‘ŠTáL—_fMIXu*TXËÅ¢T¼–L\™6Ñ¬êá"   'O4×Žç#ûcž£Töej µ¬C8Õú=£lÔ;O¶~—ÀCâ1/¨_Zâ‹ËÂt    "–e¹Êx”éÄÏ¿EÔDTíJLHEàêSA´ÀæsˆîœW¹þÿÕOö½”*çNèá7…D¶÷ç>œîC`†EñýîJa÷ØÎ Ì”sòŽT€º3n£Ð&­±‘W_ä4÷‡˜xD·÷`þ`Ü]}¥ÆÏÖKj©¿+1ý¢°g|î×’xãŽ1‰ÁïÆ1ÒJ–ÓlVÃ°`ÚÌ„p{_Gè¶ƒI„t¨èÑB£¥£Ë¸Ü9&=L[ßû†ƒ²W39nEQhåÂ³î¬ò«fêˆ£&#.ÏïÜŠ œžJî×_‹Ô¸³QOCA¦Õ$1†ÞþŽmTyT–@\9ˆ~êaH‘5Y)²PÃ$î"
©ßgÀæ;ötj!vc ý’y‚ÿ1êÎ²ˆÄòzŒîVÅF÷Ihrë…©Ååîü

wn!$Žk³tÍË¢TÊ ¢ÙøŠW){Qè6PÛ¤ ¸œ>QÿXÝ•7GYGMEýp'´KÛEŽ$°ø¥7áÇ"LÄæ¾ð”cêWNéÛ_‚6V+þHÐ¢ö×Éc9×5¤Í­ú±Â*ÍÚWELu$A›Ù«’mê;¯;Ÿó9lhcbï˜Ýöƒû·p„ßÀ0¨°ù°c–ÖzÇ!#ã»ÏË2Yé3•Çv-A%ÄÖ·äuÞ@ÖËD\œuŽˆs…¬ºÛÌk¹öðU…¿‹.úè¦®_^`¦cU€1hàã”^Å¡ò‰5

This makes no sense to me, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: it certainly looks like the file was encrypted. have you enabled some form of disk encryption, and if so, did you provide the correct key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the "Maxtor Encryption ver 2.0.1.1.0", I'd say the file is encrypted.   Use the Seagate/Maxtor Encryption software (should be supplied with the Maxtor/Seagate drive the file resided on, or you can dig it from [here](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/)) to [decrypt it](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/204091en) before opening it in Excel.

Comment: You are awesome, it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Nice! Glad you had the software around. :)